# RedisCache' object has no attribute 'ttl'

Tags: python, django, redis-cache, django-redis, django-4.0

hello friends in new project i use Django4 and i set the "django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache" for the cache but i have the error it say
"AttributeError: 'RedisCache' object has no attribute 'ttl'" .it refer to the line of my code that i add it below :

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def validate_token(token, check_time=True):
 if cache.ttl(token) == 0:
     return False
 try:
     data = claim_token(token)
 except Exception:
    return False
 if "type" not in data.keys():
    return False
```

can anyone tell me how i can resolve it ? (i know ttl mean time to live)

Comment: I think you should use the `django-redis` package. And if you are already using it, you should set `"BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache"`, [as per the django-redis doc](https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis). `ttl` is a especial function that is only available through the `django-redis` package

Comment: i installed "django-redis" package but i have this. error and i set        
  "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache" but i have this error...i dont know what is wrong?

Comment: if you are using django-redis, you should set "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache", [as per the django-redis doc.](https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis)

Comment: i want to know  why it is not compatible with "django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache"

Comment: because `ttl` is a special function that is exposed through the use of `django-redis`. The original RedisCache just does not have support ttl. That's all

Comment: but i need to ttl(time to live )how to  have it in djnago4 with "django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache"